# Unable to apt-get upgrade mariadb but dist-upgrade works? why is this?

Tags: debian, apt, mariadb

Unable to `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` mariadb on debian 8.4, I have used this way of updating always, and this is the first time I see this message:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
mariadb-server mariadb-server-10.1
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

But when I `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` it seems to work? Why is this? is there any issues this could cause?

Comment: It would help if you could also show the output from `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Answer (score 3):

There's a reason why there are two commands: `upgrade` only upgrades packages but never deletes any or installs any extra, whereas `dist-upgrade` can also add and remove packages if necessary to upgrade everything that can be upgraded. For example, if the newer version of `mariadb-server` depends on a newer library version, `apt upgrade` won't install the new library, so it'll skip the upgrade of `mariadb-server`. On the other hand, `apt-get dist-upgrade` will install the newer library.